# How to get the angle of a 3d plane using the position of the 4 corners

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, 3d, trigonometry

About 6 months ago i started making a 3d graphics engine.
Its already looking very good. I already implemented rotation, translation, scaling, Z-buffer(painter's algoritm),... Im now working on a specular shader. For that i need some way to get the angle of he individual faces
My question is, how do i get the angle of a plane by only knowing the position of the four corners?

Here is what i got so far:

```
function faceAngle(verts,faces){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0;i<faces.length;i++){
    var posA = verts[faces[i][0]];//the four corners
    var posB = verts[faces[i][1]];//    A       B
    var posC = verts[faces[i][2]];//      -----
    var posD = verts[faces[i][3]];//     |     |
                                  //     |     |
    var ar = [];                  //      -----
    ar.push(/*some Maths*/);//x   //    D       C
    ar.push(/*some Maths*/);//y
    ar.push(/*some Maths*/);//z
    arr.push(ar);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Angle... between plane and what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orientation of plane in the space is defined by normal vector. To get this vector, calculate [cross product of two edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) (belonging to the plane). So you need only three non-collinear points in the plane.

```
n = (posB - posA) x (posC - posA)   //cross product of two vectors
```

Note that components of normalized (unit) normal vector are [direction cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine)

Comment: Im sorry for my poor understanding of this topic. But how do i calculate the orientation of the plane using the normal vector? Do i have to use the pythagorean theorem to calculate the angle of the line between the center of the face and the normal vector and the 3 axises? Because i want to return the angles in radian.

Comment: @DylanMissuwe The orientation of the plane *is* the normal vector; but if you are looking to convert it to spherical polar angles, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Vector_fields).

Comment: @Dylan Missuwe That is why I asked - what angles do you mean. Normal vector is the best characterization of orientation. All other parameters might be deduced from normal

Comment: @MBo Thank you i finally got it. I thought the "X" meant multiply.